# JPA / Hibernate: Ordered list throws ConstraintViolationException

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm currently working with Hibernate 5.3.7 and trying to use ordered list - which is done by the JPA annotation @OrderColumn. My entities look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_order", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "TestOrderNumberIndex", columnNames = { "number" }) })
public class TestOrderEntity extends AbstractEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String number;
    private String customer;
    private List<TestOrderItemEntity> items;

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", targetEntity = TestOrderItemEntity.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    @OrderColumn(name = "item_index", nullable = false)
    public List<TestOrderItemEntity> getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<TestOrderItemEntity> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "test_order_item", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "TestOrderItemOrderArticleNumberIndex", columnNames = { "order_id",
                "article_number" }) })
public class TestOrderItemEntity extends AbstractEntity {
    private Long id;
    private TestOrderEntity order;
    private String articleNumber;
    private Integer amount;

    ...

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = TestOrderEntity.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.REMOVE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FKTestOrderItemTestOrder"))
    public TestOrderEntity getOrder() {
        return this.order;
    }

    public void setOrder(TestOrderEntity order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
}
```

The DDL created by Hibernate looks like this:

```
create table test_order (
    id bigint not null,
    customer varchar(255) not null,
    number varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (id)
);

create table test_order_item (
    id bigint not null,
    amount integer not null,
    article_number varchar(255) not null,
    order_id bigint,
    item_index integer not null,
    primary key (id)
);

create unique index TestOrderNumberIndex on test_order (number)

create unique index TestOrderItemOrderArticleNumberIndex on test_order_item (order_id, article_number)

alter table test_order_item
    add constraint FKTestOrderItemTestOrder foreign key (order_id) references test_order
```

The `item_index` can be seen in the `create table test_order_item` statement. So Hibernate notices the `@OrderColumn` annotation.
I execute the following code within one transaction:

```
EntityManager em;
TestOrderEntity o;
TestOrderItemEntity i1, i2;

o = new TestOrderEntity();
o.setNumber("123");
o.setCustomer("ACME");

i1 = new TestOrderItemEntity();
i1.setArticleNumber("ABC-123");
i1.setAmount(Integer.valueOf(123));

i2 = new TestOrderItemEntity();
i2.setArticleNumber("XYZ-321");
i2.setAmount(Integer.valueOf(321));

o.setItems(new ArrayList<>(i1, i2));
i1.setOrder(o);
i2.setOrder(o);

em.persist(o);
```

I would have expected that JPA / Hibernate would simply persist the entities in the database and filling the `item_index` automatically (especially as I don't have any access to it - there is no corresponding field in the TestOrderItemEntity). But what I get is the following exception (shortened form):

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'ITEM_INDEX'  cannot accept a NULL value.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    ...
Caused by: ERROR 23502: Column 'ITEM_INDEX'  cannot accept a NULL value.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong? Did I miss another annotation or an annotation parameter? Based on other Internet sources as well as the documentation everything is correct.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/collections.html#collections-list

**EDIT:**

As I read that some people solved the problem by replacing `cascade = {  CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE }` by `cascade = {  CascadeType.ALL }`, I tried that as well. But it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tries I found my mistake (and what the difference between all the working examples and my approach was): I used the annotation `@OrderColumn(name = "item_index", nullable = false)` - all the examples use `@OrderColumn(name = "item_index")`. I originally added the `nullable = false` as I thought "yes, man, I always want to have that sort criteria / index for my list, so why should it be nullable?". But it seems that parameters serves a different purpose - *if any purpose at all* (maybe someone who has more information about that can share his knowledge in the comments).

Using `@OrderColumn(name = "item_index")` I can see the following in the log (if SQL logging for Hibernate is activated):

```
Hibernate: 
    /* insert org.example.TestOrderEntity
        */ insert 
        into
            test_order
            (customer, number, id) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert org.example.TestOrderItemEntity
        */ insert 
        into
            test_order_item
            (amount, article_number, order_id, id) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert org.example.TestOrderItemEntity
        */ insert 
        into
            test_order_item
            (amount, article_number, order_id, id) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    update
        test_order_item 
    set
        item_index=? 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    update
        test_order_item 
    set
        item_index=? 
    where
        id=?
```

Up until this point I thought that the `item_index` will be inserted during the initial insert of the entity. But it isn't. Therefore having a NOT NULL column kills the approach of Hibernate. Also I'm wondering why Hibernate uses extra SQL statements for doing that as the index position is known beforehand. Sure, the ID will be created during the initial insert. But it doesn't need to be known during the initial insert which could have included the `item_index` column value.